Cannot query nested array within Redshift Struct
I have a table in AWS Redshift Spectrum that contains a column called "data".
Each cell in "Data" contains an array of JSON objects. A single data cell may look like this (this is as retrieved from the source), there will be multiple rows:
column name:data
[
{"id":1,"group":{"group_id":3,"coordinates":[23.1,23.5]}},
{"id":2,"group":{"group_id":2,"coordinates":[25.1,25.5]}},
{"id":5,"group":{"group_id":3,"coordinates":[24.1,24.5]}}
]

I would like to query the data column to fetch all of this information, keeping a single line per id.
The following works:
select 
x.id, 
x.group.group_id
from table_name a, a.data as x

returning a table with columns "id" and "group_id".
The following is what I want to be able to do:
select x.id, 
x.group.group_id, 
x.group.coordinates[0] as latitude, 
x.group.coordinates[1] as longitude
from table_name a, a.data as x

This returns the error:
ARRAY type "x.group.coordinates" can only occur in the FROM or the SELECT clause

I tried to query just the "group" as a string of sorts (select x.group from...), returned this error:
Struct type "x.group" cannot be accessed directly. Hint: Use dot notation to access specific attributes of the struct.

I can cross join the coordinates to split them into separate lines, but then I'll need to pivot it out and possibly lose the correct order (this also seems very backwards to me)?
select 
x.id, 
x.group.group_id,
y

from table_name a, a.data as x, x.group.coordinates y

Alternatively I can subquery the coordinates array, but that only works if it's in the "from" statement, and I don't know how to get the first and last value (instead of max and min which won't always work)
SELECT 
    x.id,
    (SELECT MIN(coord) FROM x.group.coordinates coord) AS latitude,
    (SELECT MAX(coord) FROM x.group.coordinates coord) AS latitude
FROM
    table_name a, a.data AS x

The "data" column contains rather large json arrays. They are not "Super" data, but rather "array<struct<" with around 60 fields per array item (around 600 items in each array).
select `json_serialize(data) 
from table_name

returns the following error:

SUPER value exceeds export size

While select json_serialize(array) from table_name x, x.data as array returns this error (and this error, or the "can only occur in the select or from clause" error is returned pretty much no matter what I put within the json_serialize function)

Struct type "array" cannot be accessed directly

I've also tried manually iterating out the components in the array, or splitting them into batches, but I continue to hit errors around nesting, or not being able to refer to fields in nested queries.
eg:
select x.data[ser.i] 
from table_name x
cross join table_ser ser

returns an error (table_ser is just a list of numbers from 1-1000)
but:
select data[0] from table_name

works just fine.

This is covered in the AWS Redshift doc here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html
There's an example of unnesting multi-level arrays that should give you the info you are looking for.  It looks like:
CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT json_parse('[[1.1, 1.2], [2.1, 2.2], [3.1, 3.2]]') AS multi_level_array;

SELECT array, element FROM foo AS f, f.multi_level_array AS array, array AS element;

   array   | element
-----------+---------
 [1.1,1.2] | 1.1
 [1.1,1.2] | 1.2
 [2.1,2.2] | 2.1
 [2.1,2.2] | 2.2
 [3.1,3.2] | 3.1
 [3.1,3.2] | 3.2
(6 rows)

===============================================
It looks like you don't want to unroll both arrays - just index the second one.  You are hitting some of the Redshift limitations with super data types.  Once you start unrolling the data structures don't allow the indexing you want.  You need to create new indexable structures.  This works with the AWS example:
SELECT array, JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT(json_serialize(array),0) as lat, 
    JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT(json_serialize(array),1) as lon
FROM foo AS f, f.multi_level_array AS array;

Is this what you want?
====================================================
In the example above lower array is converted to a json text string for parsing using json functions, not super data type addressing.  This avoids the internal data structure issue of not being able to address the unnested portions of a super data column as their own unique super data elements with their own super internal addressing.  (Good place for a Redshift enhancement request?)
So if I use your data example from the question and apply the query structure from the AWS example data I get:
create table foo as select json_parse('[
{"id":1,"group":{"group_id":3,"coordinates":[23.1,23.5]}},
{"id":2,"group":{"group_id":2,"coordinates":[25.1,25.5]}},
{"id":5,"group":{"group_id":3,"coordinates":[24.1,24.5]}}
]') as x;

SELECT x, JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json_serialize(array),'id') as id,
  JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json_serialize(array),'group',
'group_id') as group_id,
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT(JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json_serialize(array),'group',
'coordinates'), 0) as lat,
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_TEXT(JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(json_serialize(array),'group',
'coordinates'), 1) as lon
FROM foo AS f, f.x AS array;

Other than carrying the original super value 'x' into the final result I believe this is the result you desire.
===========================================
You report that unnesting the first level array and converting to text exceeds the max varchar so fully unrolling will be needed to get manageable chucks of data.  You haven't shown any updated view into your data structure so I'll assume the same as you originally posted, just that things are too big for varchar.
create table foo as select json_parse('[
{"id":1,"group":{"group_id":3,"coordinates":[23.1,23.5]}},
{"id":2,"group":{"group_id":2,"coordinates":[25.1,25.5]}},
{"id":5,"group":{"group_id":3,"coordinates":[24.1,24.5]}}
]') as x;

with l1 as (
  SELECT array.id, array.group.group_id, coord, index
  FROM foo AS f, f.x AS array, array."group"."coordinates" AS coord AT index)
SELECT id, group_id, min(decode(index,0,coord)) as lat, min(decode(index,1,coord)) as lon
FROM l1
group by id, group_id;

This query unnests both array levels and then combines the coordinates back on to the same row using the index from the lower array (coordinates).  This isn't as efficient since it expands into additional rows and recombines but given the constraints it seems needed.
If more adjustments are needed you will need to provide a detailed description of the data you are using.

I saw this and already accomplished this in my question - however I lose the order of the array objects (unless you can suggest a way to enforce them?). Even so, after this I'd then need to pivot out the values to get them in separate columns which is the desired outcome.

So on the same page there is extracting the INDEX from the array and you could use this for the ordering when you pivot. But is sounds like you don't want to unroll both arrays.  I'll update the answer

So this is exactly what I want, but unfortunately does not work for me, I get this error:
ARRAY type "x.group.coordinates" can only occur in the FROM or the SELECT clause
(or in this case it's "array.group.coordinates")

since there seems to be an issue with communicating that the coordinates need to be addressed as a different data structure I'll update the answer for your data example.

This is indeed the result I desire - and your example code is prefect if using the simple version of the table (foo) above.
In this case, I should've clarified in the question that my table is far larger, and the column is actually not of type "super" but defined as <array<struct<..... with +- 60 fields in it. (each entry has a few hundred records in the top-level array). I've updated the question to show this.
The problem then is that the column contents cannot be converted using "json_serialize" (error: "super exceeds export size")

OK a few things. 1) you really should look at modifying your data model but this might be what you are trying to do with this query.  This error is due to trying to generate a varchar > 64K bytes.  2) this data is a Super data type to Redshift.  3) Given all these constraints you will need to fully unroll all the arrays and bring things back together.  I'll update the answer again to show this.
